# ImportError: cannot import name 'keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When running this in Jupyter notebooks (python):

```python
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

I get this error:

```python
ImportError: cannot import name 'keras'
```

I've tried other commands in place of the second one, such as (but not limited to)

```python
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

But it always returns some error. I'm using the online version of Jupyter, and running `print(tf.VERSION)` returns 1.1.0. I'm not sure if the problem is just that I have the wrong version, or if it's something else. How do I fix this?

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: did you install tensorflow in a virtual environment?

Comment: I’m using python 3

Comment: do you have keras installed? if you are using windows python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an old version of Tensorflow; to access Keras from Tensorflow 1.1, you should use

```
import tensorflow.contrib.keras as keras
```

For Sequential, use

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
```

Comment: Where would I get that message? I just imported it in JupyterLabs and it didn’t return an error, but then I tried: model = keras.Sequential() and it returned an error.

Comment: what about for other modules, like Flatten and Dense? Would I just import the respective module and replace Sequential with Flatten or Dense? And is there a way to do it without so many import lines?

Comment: @RonanVenkat for layers,you replace `models` with `layers`. And no, with the version of Tensorflow you are using you cannot avoid the long imports...

Comment: I get an error that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'` when I try this.

Comment: @user3367130 pls open a new question with the details

Answer (score 8):

I think you are using old version `tensorflow` Try to update it like

```
! pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

Comment: How would I do that in an online Jupyter notebook (JupyterLabs)?

Comment: For a jupyter notebook just put a ! symbol before the command. It makes `! pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I also was not able to import `keras` from `tensorflow`. I was getting the
following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)`

After searching for a bit got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74625588/20337959):

All that is required is to remove `~(site_package_name)` from the directory. In my scenario, it was `~ensorflow` and it was somehow blocking the pip to install/upgrade packages. Once I deleted the folder, everything was running smoothly. After deleting the package, install/upgrade the required package.

For those, who are unable to find the directory. Here is mine (just for reference): `C:\Users\veni_\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`

Note: The warning itself will show the name of the package that is causing the problem. For e.g.:

```
 **"WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow"**
```