# "Cannot import name 'keras'" error when importing keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

Results are

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-75a28e3c6620> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 from tensorflow import keras
      3 
      4 import numpy as np
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'keras'
```

Using tensorflow version 1.2.1 and keras version 2.3.1

Comment: New to stackoverflow so if im doing anything wrong just tell me

Comment: you can try the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847380/importerror-cannot-import-name-keras

Comment: It seems to be working now but won't complete the task in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'keras'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847380/importerror-cannot-import-name-keras)

Answer (score 1):

You are using old version of tensorflow. You can update to latest version using below code

```
! pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

From `Tensorflow V2.0` onwards, keras is integrated in tensorflow as `tf.keras`, so no need to import keras separately.

To create sequential model, you can refer below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

#Define Sequential model with 3 layers
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
    ]
)
# Call model on a test input
x = tf.ones((3, 3))
y = model(x)

print("Number of weights after calling the model:", len(model.weights))  # 6

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Number of weights after calling the model: 6
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
layer1 (Dense)               (3, 2)                    8         
_________________________________________________________________
layer2 (Dense)               (3, 3)                    9         
_________________________________________________________________
layer3 (Dense)               (3, 4)                    16        
=================================================================
Total params: 33
Trainable params: 33
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

For more details please refer [Tensorflow Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model). I am happy to help you, if you are not able to complete the task.