# why do I receive these errors "WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yproj " while installing any python module in cmd

Tags: python, geopandas, torch, fiona, osgeo

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yproj (c:\users\space_junk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yproj (c:\users\space_junk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yproj (c:\users\space_junk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)

Answer (score 15):

I was getting a similar message that turned out be caused by a previous failed pip upgrade.  I had attempted to upgrade pip from a user account that didn't have the proper rights.  There was a temp directory left behind in site-packages that began with ~ip which was causing pip to complain every time it ran.  I removed the directory and was able to re-upgrade pip using an account that had proper permissions.  No more warnings from pip.

Did you have a problem installing something like pyproj by any chance?  The temp directory seems to be named by replacing the first letter of the library with a ~.

Comment: yeah I had such problem but on trying your answer, everything is now okay, thanks!!

Comment: I'm far from an expert on package installation, but here's what I've learned from debugging this issue and many others connected to it: Check if there are packages (usually in your site-packages ) that begin with ~, meaning they were temporary files that never got cleaned up after an error in installation. If you find any, delete them!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with matplotlib. It looked like I wanted to install a package from some sort of unauthorized source.

You should delete the folder that caused the problem in site-packages folder. In your case, it is ~yproj (In my case, it was ~atplotlib).

In short :

1. Find the site-packages folder -> Type "pip show pyproj" or any other library you want!
2. Delete the folder mentioned in the warning : `~yproj` in your case